# Cant install Laravel 6

Tags: php, laravel, installation

I want to install Laravel 6 with Composer. I try with that command:

```
composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel laravel6 "6.*"
```

But i get that result:

```
  [InvalidArgumentException]                                
  Could not find package laravel/laravel with version 6.*.
```

[Here is a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5a3c5.png)

If i use:

```
composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel blog
```

It install the v5.5.28
[Here is a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BLXaN.png)

What can be the problem?

Comment: I think you can just omit `"6.*` and it should install at version 6. From the Laravel docs: https://laravel.com/docs/6.x `composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel blog`

Comment: Please list your OS, PHP Version to assist with determing the issue

Comment: @TimLewis that command install the v5.5.28

Comment: Hmm... Is your `composer` out of date? if Laravel documentation says that it should install `6.0` with that command, that might be the case.

Comment: @TimLewis how i can update composer? i dont find that in Google.

Comment: Did you search for "Update composer"? Cause I did, and found this: https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#self-update-selfupdate-: *"To update Composer itself to the latest version, run the self-update command."*

Comment: @TimLewis that command updates the version of Composer, then the message that i get is: "You are already using composer version 1.9.0 (stable channel)."

Answer (score 3):

Which `PHP` version you are using? `Laravel-6.*` need `PHP >= 7.2.0`. Check your [server-requirements](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x#server-requirements) for `Laravel 6.*`. May be you did not meeting the [requirements](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x#server-requirements) for `laravel 6.*`. And after meeting the requirements run your command inside `htdocs` folder for `xampp` or `www` folder for `wamp` webserver.

Comment: I think he needs full fill server requirements for `laravel-6.*`. His installation command is correct and it's working in my machine. You can see this image link - https://ibb.co/cJnN6cw

Answer (score 2):

your command are no longer supports so you should use:

```
composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel="6.*" laravel6
```

Comment: That return the following error:     [InvalidArgumentException]                                
  Could not find package laravel/laravel with version 6.*.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to add the "--prefer-dist " . So in your case, you have to use the:

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel --prefer-dist
```

in order to make it work. So just remove all the files from: d:\xampp\htdocs\laravel and then try again by following the below commands to your cmd (I guess you are using Windows!):

```
 cd d:\xampp\htdocs\laravel
```

composer create-project laravel/laravel --prefer-dist

I think this should work for you just fine

Comment: "composer create-project **--prefer-dist** laravel/laravel laravel6" - They didn't forget it, it was just earlier in the command.

Comment: the command:"composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel laravel6"  - Install the v5.5.28 version

Comment: @DharmikUnagar i posted the screenshot in the post

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to specify the version of Laravel 6. By default, Laravel 6 installs the latest version and its extension.

As I'm writing now the current and latest version of Laravel is: Laravel 6.0.4
The command below will install the current and the latest version in your laravel6 project.

composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel laravel6

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to specify the version of Laravel 6. By default, Laravel 6 installs the latest version and its extension.

**Via Composer Create-Project**

Alternatively, you may also install Laravel by issuing the Composer create-project command in your terminal:

```
composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel your_project_name
```

I think it will be helpful for you. for more details visit laravel official website : https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/installation

Answer (score 1):

Kindly upgrade your PHP version on your system.

Then install laravel commands
It will automatically install the lettest version depends on the PHP version.

Or you can mention on laravel command and set the laravel version like "6.0*" behind the laravel installer command.

I hope this will works

Answer (score 1):

Please check the permissions on the cache dir (/home/keynes/.composer/cache)
It's complaining it cannot write to this dir, or it may not exist.
Maybe it is installing an older laravel version from the cache dir.

Answer (score 0):

The commands you are running should work. I would try clearing the composer cache:

```
composer clear-cache
```

and then

```
composer update
composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel="6.*" laravel6
```

before trying again. Looking at the screenshots there seem to be some permissions errors in the `~/.composer` directory. This might also cause the `composer clear-cache` command to fail with an error.

So if clearing the cache doesn't work or you get an error, you might try moving the `~/.composer` directory to a backup location, to force composer to regenerate it's settings.

```
mv ~/.composer ~/.composer.backup
```

And then try it again (be aware that `composer update` will likely take a noticeably longer time than usual and might be unresponsive for a while):

```
composer update
composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel="6.*" laravel6
```

If it still doesn't work, then you can restore the backup:

```
rm -rf ~/.composer
mv ~/.composer.backup ~/.composer
```

Then looking at the output of

```
composer config --list --global
```

might help determine the next thing to try.